# c++ (gcc -O2 on Linux) Looking to speed up an array copy for loop with rotation

Tags: c++, arrays, memcpy, memset

I'm running a large ammt of data thru some code, and with profiling I've found two bottlenecks, the first I was able to almost completely eliminate by switching to memset as a means of initializing the arrays, but the second I can't figure out how to speed up.

The program takes as much as 11 hours to run sometimes, so any improvement would be important.

```
rows=new char[size];

//for(i=0;i<size;i++){
//  rows[i]='0';
//}
memset(rows,'0',size);
//using memset instead, cut the runtime contribution of that function from 20% down to 1%!!

call_lots_of_functions_not_included_here();

char *old_rows=rows;
rows=new char[xCount*yCount];
//    for(x=0;x<xCount;x++){
//      for(y=0;y<yCount;y++){
//        rows[y*xCount+(xCount-1-x)] = old_rows[x*yCount+y];  
//      }
//    }

int z=-1;
int i=-1;
for(x=0;x<xCount;x++){
 i=xCount-x-1;
 for(y=1;y<yCount;y++){
   i+=xCount;
   rows[i]=old_rows[z++];
 }
}

//By eliminating the y*xCount stuff, I was able to reduce the runtime to 1/5th original!
//But I can't help but think it can still be made faster... faaaster.
delete[] old_rows;
```

This for loop is at 26% of total program runtime, If I could figure out how to optimize it   similar to the prior function, it'd be a big deal.

Note: looping thru the array and setting each char to '0' took 20% time, while looping thru the array and setting each char to be some specific value took 26% time, so the problem is NOT the array allocation, or deletion... there are simply a lot of characters being set.

```
note: example input vs output data (this function rotates a bitmap 90 degrees)
in     out     in_flattened
 0123   012    abcdefghijkl
0abcd  0iea    
1efgh  1jfb    out_flattened
2ijkl  2kgc    ieajfbkgclhd
       3lhd
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your complier likely does this already, but you can remove the if/else by just assigning `i=xCount-x-1` before the second `for` loop and starting at `y=1`

Comment: why not use memcpy for the internal part?

Comment: I'm confused.  You create rows, clear it, and point old_rows to rows.  Then you create rows again (of a potentially different size), then start copying from old_rows to rows.  Aren't you just copying the zeros over?

Comment: @namfuak Thanks that brought it down from 560 to 485! we began at 2700, so we're really cruisin.

Comment: @leeor not sure how? i+=xCount makes memcpy not really fit.

Comment: Use a vector and resize it instead of allocating new arrays.

Comment: `old_rows[z++]` so you are accessing `old_rows[-1]`???

Comment: Why didn't you try `-O3`? gcc is able to recognize the first loop and replace it with memset.

Comment: You could try working by blocks, say of size 4x4, so you would read 4 int, figure out some optimized way of getting 4 "rotated" int, and store those. You could also try to work in place (not creating a new matrix), it might save on the memory accesses.